# I'm trying to find the subtotal of the selected items

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the prices of the items in an array:

```
double[] productPriceArray = { 1162.99, 399.99, 329.99, 199.99, 149.99 };
```

I am trying to find the total of the ones that a user puts in a "cart". I'm not sure how to go about that. I know I can use the line of code:

```
subtotal = productCostArray[lbxCart.SelectedIndex];  
lblSubtotal.Text = subtotal.ToString("c");
```

to find the total of one of the indices, but how can I find the total of multiple indices?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your "cart" have an array of indices?  If so, a `for` loop is probably easiest.

Comment: What do you mean "total of multiple indices"

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in the current design , You need atleast a list of product and product price mapping then you need a list of products in the cart and in the cart class you can  define a function to get the subtotal of all products.

```
public class  Product
{
    public string ProductId { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public double Price { get; set; }
}

public class ShoppingCart
{
    public string CartId { get; set; }

    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public void AddProductToCart(Product p)
    {
        if(Products==null)
            Products = new List<Product>();
         if(p!=null)
                 Products.Add(p);

    }

    public double CartPrice()
    {
        return Products != null ? Products.Sum(p => p.Price):0D;
    }
}
```

and usage

```
 var shopCart = new ShoppingCart();
        shopCart.AddProductToCart(new Product {ProductId = "1",Price = 12.09, ProductName = "P1"});
          shopCart.AddProductToCart(new Product {ProductId = "2",Price = 11.09, ProductName = "P2"});
        MessageBox.Show(shopCart.CartPrice().ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of selected item indices (as your example appears to suggest), you could do:

```
var subtotal = SelectedIndices.Select(idx => productPriceArray[idx]).Sum();
```

Comment: What if two different product has the same price?